# Как убрать часть текста из ячейки?

Tags: excel

Изначально в ячейке *Excel* идет так:

```
<tr>
<td>Цвет корпуса</td>
<td style="width:160px">Белый</td>
</tr><tr class="sp">
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в ячейке убрать эту часть:

```
<tr class="sp">
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Поиск-замена не срабатывает, точнее вообще не находит этого ни в одной ячейке, а у меня их около 3 000 шт.
Может есть какие-то макросы, функции, не знаю хоть что то..

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Есть функция. Назвается "Поиск-замена". Если не срабатывает, значит неправильно используется.

Comment: я и написал, что поиск не находит эту часть, хотя я ее копирую прям из самой ячейки.

Comment: А я и написал, что неправильно используется. В экселе у поиска несколько режимов.

Comment: тогда подскажите как надо, пожалуйста..

Comment: Под рукой экселя нет. Там где-то есть галочка в опциях поиска, что текст должен совпадать со всей ячейкой. Она должна быть не нажата.

Comment: Есть такое: чекбокс Ячейка целиком. Ставлю и не ставлю - пока бестолку..

Comment: Тогда странно. А в "ОБласть поиска" что выбрано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr class="sp">(ctrl+j)<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>(ctrl+j)</tr>
```

вводится в окне поиска/замены.

Answer (score 0):

Для переноса текста в другую строку (в одной ячейке) существует специальный символ переноса строки - `СИМВОЛ(10)`. Инструмент *НАЙТИ/ЗАМЕНИТЬ* видит вместо символа переноса строка `СИМВОЛ(32)` -  пробел. Естественно, фрагмента с пробелам он не находит.

Чтобы инструмент справился с таким текстом, нужны дополнительные движения по преобразованию текста. Гораздо проще удалить фрагмент формулой.

Против текстов в свободном столбце записать удаляемые фрагменты. Если удаляемая часть одна для всех текстов, не нужно для нее выделять столбец, можно записать в одну ячейку.

Еще в один столбец внести формулу и протянуть ее на нужное количество строк.

Пример.

В столбце *А* тексты, в столбце *В* (или только в ячейке B1) - удаляемый фрагмент.

В столбце *С* формула:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;B2;)
```

Для общего фрагмента:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;$B$1;)
```

Для данного случая можно  взять только левую часть:

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК("class=";A2)-5)
```

Иногда нужно удалить текст одной строки. При этом останется пустая строка, т.к. два символа переноса расположены один за другим. Для такого случая:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;$B$1;);СИМВОЛ(10)&СИМВОЛ(10);СИМВОЛ(10))
```

Дальнейшие действия - по необходимости.

а) оставить как есть;

б) выделить ячейки с формулами, копировать, выделить диапазон исходных текстов, вставить (но! *Вставить_как_значения*); столбцы *В* и *С* можно очистить или удалить;

в) выделить ячейки с формулами, копировать, здесь же вставить (но! *Вставить_как_значения*); столбцы *А* и *В* можно очистить или удалить.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, пока не опробовал. Сработает такой метод, если в каждой ячейке по несколько раз встречается этот ненужный кусок кода? Ну то есть код идет так: нужный кусок, ненужный, нужный, ненужный..

Comment: *ПОДСТАВИТЬ* удалит все фрагменты, не трогая другой текст. Формула с *ЛЕВБ* удалит все после первого вхождения слова *"class="* (точнее, начиная с 5-го символа влево от слова).

Comment: Спасибо, способ не успел ваш опробовать, но узнал о таком способе, поэтому его бы тоже отметить решением. В поиске/замене, получается после первой и второй строчки вставил символ ctrl+j и сразу стали находиться эти куски, ну а заменил на просто на пустоту.
<tr class="sp">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>